# What reason should I pick when closing a Super User question?

Tags: support, migration, close-reasons

When reviewing the Close Votes queue, it's not unusual to come across questions that are off-topic and would be more suitable to be posted on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com). However, sometimes I doubt what reason to choose, whether just close or migrate.

I understand that the first one just closes the question and leaves it on Stack Overflow, whereas the migration would automatically move the question to Super User. This is, however, the only one "*conflictive*" reason, as Super User is the only site that appears both on the off-topic and migration submenus.

**Off-topic close reason**

[image: gch]

**Migration close reason**

[image: migr]

Is there some clear rule that should be applied here? If not, what criteria do you apply when you face these questions?

Comment: One case I saw: two people voted to migrate, I voted to close as "General computing and hardware". Question was closed as "not about programming" with no mention of SuperUser, even though all voters selected a SuperUser option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only migrate *quality* questions; close the rest.

When voting to close a post as off-topic the SuperUser.com link points to the [Super User about page](https://superuser.com/about), which gives the user a chance to re-learn how to ask questions.

But if the question is of sufficient quality (e.g. you'd vote it up if it was posted directly on Super User), then by all means vote to migrate it.

I'd err on the side of caution myself; rather close a good but off-topic question than migrate a bad one.

Comment: Crazy idea that'll probably never work: unlock migration paths in the close dialog only when the user has upvoted the question.

Comment: That would be a good idea, since it would make sure the user has some idea about the question and therefore might have some criteria to decide, this would however need to enable up/down voting in the close queue

Comment: Can users here really be trusted (or relied upon) in judging question quality for SuperUser? From what I can see from my experience, all the questions tend to be voted to close as off-topic. Even if the problem is formulated quite well.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: we keep tabs on migrations all the time; for example, in the past 90 days, 71 posts were migrated to Super User, and only 1% of those were rejected. That's the lowest rejection rate of all the default-path migrations (where the community votes rather than moderators do the job manually).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: so, as far as SU migrations are concerned, it looks like we can trust and rely on users.