# Why do some sites have migration paths but not close reasons? Why do some sites have close reasons but not migration paths?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

Currently, two sites across the Stack Exchange network are explicitly mentioned in the vote to close reasons:

[image]

- Super User is mentioned explicitly in a **close** reason.
- Server Fault is mentioned explicitly in a **close** reason.

---

And there are five sites offered as migration paths from Stack Overflow:

[image]

- Meta Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Tex
- Database Administrators
- Cross Validated

---

I understand the difference between [when you should use a close vote versus a migration vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252291/2792531).

I understand there are a limited number of custom reasons, so not *all* of the migration paths can also have special reasons in the custom close reasons.  I also understand why some sites aren't offered as migration paths (like Programmers).

But...

- why does Super User need both a close reason and a migration reason?
- why does Server Fault need a close reason (which recommends the user might have a question suitable for that site), but it doesn't need a migration path?
- why do Tex, Database Admins, and Cross Validated need migration paths but do not need close vote reasons?

I'm interested both in *specific* reasons for these specific sites being set up as they are (migration path versus close reason and why some have one, some have the other, and one has both options).

Are we implying that SO close voters can't be trusted to migrate good questions to Server Fault, but they are good at identifying questions that are off-topic on SO and *might* be fit for Server Fault?

Are we implying that SO close voters are good at identifying questions that should be migrated to, say, Cross Validated, but we don't see questions asked that *might* be fit for Cross Validated, but we should just *close* them and point the user to the Cross Validated help center?

Are we saying that we see both questions that would be a perfect fit for Super User and can be migrated as is as well as questions that *might* be fit for Super User but would probably be better simply closing on SO?

Comment: That dialog quotes the exact message that the OP sees.  Maybe you'll be less confused if you can't see the hint that the user gets?  Then again, maybe you shouldn't vote if you're confused.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not confused about which close/migration reason to use and when.  I'm confused about why the options are what they are.  How come there isn't a migration option for Server Fault but there is a close reason?  How come there's a migration option for Tex, but there's not a close reason?

Comment: Regarding Server Fault not having a migration path, this is explained in [Flagging question as off topic - where is ServerFault option?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185223/209901): _Too many bad questions were being migrated from Stack Overflow to Server Fault. Rather than letting that continue to happen, Server Fault was removed from the list._

Comment: @fedorqui I'm guessing this is the same reason for not including programmers?

Comment: @Pureferret I wasn't aware of it but yes, in fact it is also blocked as explained in [When flagging a question it should be markable that it belongs to programmers.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135239/209901). In fact there is a list of migration paths in [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134636/209901), only that it doesn't look quite updated (last time was in 2012).