# Please collapse OT "belongs on SuperUser" with "belongs on another site -> SU"

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, user-experience

When a question has been voted as off-topic multiple times, you sometimes find that the "Closing>Off-topic" pseudo-dialog shows a small blue balloon with a number next to one of the hard-coded nominee sites ([Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)) indicating that some close voters nominated that site; and also a small blue balloon next to "This site belongs to another site in the StackExchange network", indicating that some other close voters nominated a different site.

[image: Sorry for the freehand art (not!!)]

But lo, sometimes the "different site" is SU or SF as well, and you just wasted a precious click finding out this useless piece of information (probably in the hope that a previous close voter came up with a much better destination for a possible migration, in spite of [the hassle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites))

[image: See, more freehand art!!]

Could we please have all the close votes collected in the first dialog when this happens?

Comment: _"you just wasted a precious click..."_ I'd sue them. Clicks are a precious resource, just like solar power, that ___will run out!___

Comment: Clicks consume time and temper.  If you disagree, why are you not using `telnet meta.stackoverflow.com 80` to view this site?  (If you are, my sincerest apologies and humble admiration.)

Comment: Nah, I agree with the suggestion, it was just a joke ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> next to one of the hard-coded nominee sites (Super User and Server Fault) indicating that some close voters nominated that site

No, they didn't nominate that site as a migration target. They voted to close the question without migrating it, with an explanation that *mentions* Super User to the author. Other users disagreed and voted to *migrate* to SU.  (They won't win in this particular case, since migration from SO requires 4 votes out of 5 to be for migration.)

The difference between two kinds of votes is not a trivial one, and pretending that all previous voters  agreed on an action when they didn't would be misleading.

- [What reason should I pick when closing a Super User question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252291/what-reason-should-i-pick-when-closing-a-super-user-question)
- [Why do some sites have migration paths but not close reasons? Why do some sites have close reasons but not migration paths?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294017/why-do-some-sites-have-migration-paths-but-not-close-reasons-why-do-some-sites?rq=1)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not seem to agree with what I'm seeing.  I added a second picture to the question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: I'm seeing two votes to close without migrating, and two votes to migrate.

Comment: Ah, so the *top* two don't count as migration votes, only as close votes with a hint? I see now. That's absurd, again; but I see now.

Comment: @tripleee No, it isn't absurd, just subtle (maybe too much at that). Not all questions whose topic would work on SU should be migrated to SU.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sites like SO should not be subtle, they should be clear. It's that I was checking for some solutions like tripleee that I even noticed that you can do migration and just close.